# Visual Studio Cannot Locate jpeg File

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file, path, working-directory

I am trying to experiment with OpenCV's C++ Library. However, I encounter an issue when trying to read an image. Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>

#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/stitching.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main() {

    Mat image = imread("tiger.jpg");
    
    if (image.empty()) {
        cout << "No Image" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else {

        imshow("Test", image);
        waitKey(0);
        return 0;
    }

}
```

The "image" keeps evaluating as empty, implying that Visual Studio could not find my image. I have included the image into my project directory and have even resorted to using the absolute file path but nothing seems to work.

[image: Project]

This problem has started occurring very recently and beforehand I had no problem reading images. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

I have re-written my code to see if Visual Studio could actually locate the file.

```
int main() {

    std::filesystem::path imagePath = "C:\\Images\\flower.jpg";

    if (std::filesystem::exists(imagePath) && std::filesystem::is_regular_file(imagePath)) {
        cv::Mat image = cv::imread(imagePath.string());

        if (!image.empty()) {
            cv::imshow("My Image", image);
            cv::waitKey(0);
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Error: Could not read the image." << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Image file does not exist or is not a regular file." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

It seems to be able to locate the file, but I am still getting the error that the image is empty. I have tried with multiple different images and image extensions. Nothing seems to work. This problem only seems to occur on my Windows desktop but not on my Mac.

Comment: The default working directory when running in the IDE is set to $(ProjectDir) in the debug settings which is the same folder as the one that contains the project file. It looks like that is where you have it but some of the views sometimes can hide the actual folder structure.

Comment: learn about the current working directory and relative paths. use whatever suitable function to get the current working directory.

Comment: please post the image file and/or its first few lines of hex dump. it may have been corrupted or your program lacks permissions. -- you might have forgotten to link opencv's `imgcodecs` module or whatever else modulates the availability of jpeg decoding to OpenCV.